# How can I re-download games for Games for Windows Live?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv, games-for-windows-live

I have in the past purchased Street fighter 4 AE; I think I used to own a hard copy, but not anymore.

I logged into my Windows Live account on Xbox Live's website and I saw that I had Achievements in the game. Which means that my Windows Live account does have a Street Fighter 4 AE CD key attached to it.

How do I re-download the game if I haven't purchased it from the Windows live site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you owned the game as a CD then you need a CD to play it.  You can't just download it for free.

You can check if you purchased the game online at http://www.xbox.com:

- click on "My Account"
- click on "Billing History"
- enter your login credentials (you will end up at commerce.microsoft.com)
- click on "Transaction"
- adjust search criteria and click the "search" button.

There you should see something like "Street Fighter 4 AE: Xbox 360 Edition" as the description with a "Purchase" transaction type.

If it's there you should simply be able to download the game again either via xbox.com or directly from your Xbox.

I think this is the link to the game you're talking about:
http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/SUPER-STREETFIGHTER-IV-ARCADE-EDITION/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802434307fc

However, if it's not an online purchase then you need the CD to play it again.

Comment: am talking about the PC version

Comment: Games for WIndows live implies PC.

Answer (score 2):

The version you purchased was the retail Windows version not the on-demand version from Xbox.com. These are considered separate. Therefore, you have the following options:

- Find the original disc
- Borrow one from someone you know
- Purchase from Xbox.com
- Purchase the retail version again